# Plotting in ggplot with non-discrete x and y

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I want to create a ggplot where the x-axis is a distance (currently the distances are continuous values that range between 0 and 45 feet) that can be binned and the y-axis is whether or not the basket was made (0 is missed, 1 is made). Here is a subset of the dataframe, which is a pandas dataframe. EDIT: Not sure this is helpful, but I have also added a column that represents the bucket/bin for each attempt's shot distance.

```
distance(ft)   outcome     category
-----------    ---------   --------
9.5            1           (9,18]
23.3           1           (18,27]
18.7           0           (18,27] 
10.8           0           (9,18]
43.6           1           (36,45]
```

I could just make a scatterplot where x-axis is distance and the y-axis is miss/made. However, I don't want to visualize every shot attempt as a point. Let's say I want the x axis to be bins (where each bin is every 9 ft: 0-9 ft, 9-18 ft, 18-27 ft, 27-36 ft, 36-45 ft), and the y to be the proportion of shots that was made in that bin.

What is the best way to achieve this in ggplot? How much preprocessing do I have to do before leveraging ggplot capabilities? I can imagine doing all the necessary computation myself to find the proportion of shots made per bin and then plotting those values easily, but I feel there should be some built-in capabilities to help me with this (although I am new to ggplot and unsure at this point). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are likely using a Pandas DataFrame (or Series) to hold your data, right?

If so, you can bin your values [using Pandas in-built functionality](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_binning_data.html), specifically [the pandas.cut function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).

e.g.

```
bins = 9 # can be int or sequence of scalars
out, bins = df.cut(data, bins, retbins = True, include_lowest = True)
```

Comment: Yes, I am. Thanks for pointing that out! After binning, how would I find the proportion made within each bin (where proportion made is proportion of 1s over 1s or 0s in that bin)?

Comment: That'll depend on your data structure - ask a fresh question with some more info and I'll have a look.
If this has solved your issue, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Awesome! I have updated what the Pandas dataframe looks like after adding the bins in this question itself. I would like to find the proportion made for each bin.